# ownership permission is automatically changing to root for /var/www/

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I am new to ubuntu. i installed LAMP and tried to install wordpress but failed due to ownership permission then i google for this problem and found that i need to run `sudo chown -R [USER NAME]:[USER NAME] /var/www` and it helped. i installed wordpress but the main problem is that the ownership permission for /var/www is automatically being change to root after some time (after about 2-3 minutes) and the folder in /var/www is changed to some file which is saying "You have no permission to access this location" when clicking to open it. Now i can't do in this folder and neither `http://localhost` working nor `http://localhost/wordpress`, saying `You don't have permission to access /wordpress/ on this server.` with `403 forbidden error`.

how to solve this problem. I never found this problem in windows before. i really want to use linux but it frustrating me some time.

Comment: Is this system yours or a VPS or something? Which version of Ubuntu? How did you install LAMP?

Comment: modify the permissions using the following command `$ chmod -r 744 /var/www`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same `chown` command.

```
 sudo chown -R [your_username]:[your_usrename] /var/www/
```

Comment: This isn't a permanent solution, adding yourself to the apache group would be better

Comment: i think you have to recursively do it `sudo chown -r  [your_username]:[your_username]  /var/www`